# Restrictions on setting up the profile picture

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some new users like [him](https://askubuntu.com/users/237159/user237159) setting up some sexy or adultary photos as their profile picture.This SE site was not only viewed by adults but also by the minors.

So my question is that SE provides any restrictions on setting up this kind of profile pictures by new users? I think currently not but in the future.

My opinion is "New users can change or setup their profile picture on only they got 100 reputations".**Like a privelege**.

```
  100 rep    Access to change profile picture
```

Comment: Wow.. You actually got around to setting a profile picture yourself ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a strong argument for setting up restrictions on profile pictures. If you think some of those pictures are in bad taste, just flag one of their posts and ask for a moderator to take a look.

We can and do change gravatars on similar grounds (like I did for this instance) and we will be glad to entertain any similar requests.